# For a convex problem $\min_x f(x) + g(x) $, KKT point $x^*$ satisfies $0 \in \nabla f(x^*) + \partial g(x^*) $

Tags: convex-analysis

Apologies for a basic question.

For a convex problem $$\min_x f(x) + g(x) ,$$ 
where assuming $f(x)$ is differentiable with $m$-Lipschitz continuous gradient, while $g(x)$ is closed convex proper.

Then, KKT point $x^*$ satisfies $$0 \in \nabla f(x^*) + \partial g(x^*) .$$

**My question is**: Can we say $\nabla f(x^*) = 0$ at the KKT point? If yes, then it means, the subgradient $\partial g \in 0$ at the KKT Point? or do I miss any assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot say this. To give a simple example, consider
the functions $f, g \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined via
$f(x) = -g(x) = x$.
Then, every $x^* \in \mathbb R$ is a minimizer with $f'(x^*) = 1$
and $\partial g(x^*) = \{-1\}$.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Can any assumptions help to say that the gradient is zero?

Comment: I cannot think of any reasonable condition. Of course, $f \equiv 0$ or $g \equiv 0$ works...

Comment: thank you for the clarification.